# How does Ada implement 'mod' and 'range' types? What are the performance implications?

Tags: performance, types, programming-languages, ada

In Ada you can define so called '[mod](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/mod)' and '[range](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/range)' types:

```
type Unsigned_n is mod 2**n;
type Range_Type is range -5 .. 10;
```

How are these implemented at the <strike>language</strike> machine level? What kind of performance penalty do you experience when performing operations on these types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by 'at the language level'. At the Ada level, they just are! and at the machine level, they're implemented how you'd expect.

For modular types, if you use a power of 2 for the modulus, the compiled code uses masks; otherwise, there will be tests.

```
type Modular is mod 42;
...
procedure T (M : in out Modular) is
begin
   M := M + 1;
end T;
```

translates (x86_64, -O2) to

```
_foo__t:
LFB2:
        leal    1(%rdi), %eax
        cmpb    $40, %dil
        leal    -41(%rdi), %edx
        cmovg   %edx, %eax
        ret
```

I don't write assembler nowadays, but that doesn't look too bad (and, in a language that didn't support modular types, you'd have to write something similar yourself if the problem demanded it).

For integer types, the implementation is again as you'd expect, except of course that assigning a value to a variable involves a constraint check (unless the compiler can prove that there's no need).

But really, for most uses, you don't write these increment operations yourself; if you need to loop over all values of the type you can say

```
for J in Modular loop
```

or, if you have declared `Arr : array (Range_Type) of Foo;`,

```
for J in Arr'Range loop
```

and there's no need to check the validity of `J`, and therefore no performance penalty.

It's always possible to suppress constraint checks (in GNAT, `-gnatp` suppresses all checks); but it's a bit like taking the seatbelt off as soon as you leave the driveway!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, 'the machine level' is what I should have said – I'll amend my question.

Comment: Actually, if the modular type happens to fit exactly in a machine register, wouldn't the compiler just handle the wrapping situation by letting nature take its course (and ignoring any pesky overflow or carry flags)? In this case, the modular integer would be *more* efficient, as constraint checks would never be required.